# Mongo C# driver 2.0 - DeleteOneAsync inside a cursor gives unexpected results

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have done the paging implementation using the following:

```
 .Find(_ => true).Skip(PageSize * (int)(PageNumber - 1)).Limit(PageSize).ToListAsync().Result;
```

and inside of the paging code I have called DeleteOneAsync( with _id filter), I have over 5,00,000 records and the paging working fine, just that the delete api doesn't delete all the records as expected. My pseudo-code is as follows:

```
while(true)
{
   var page = GetPage(pageIdx++); //starts with 1
   if(page.Count == 0)
      break;
   foreach(var p in page)
   {
       Delete(p);
   }
}
```

There is no error raised anywhere, all the processing runs fine, but at the ends I expect all records to be deleted but I see that only a few chunk is deleted. Any clue why this happens or if there is a issue in paging part of mine?

Sample code:

```
public static class ConsoleProgram
{
    const int PAGE_SIZE = 100;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         MongoClientSettings clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings();
        clientSettings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient(clientSettings);
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("petrel");
        IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>  mt = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("PatientDocuments");
        int pageNo = 1;
        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            IEnumerable<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> page = null;
            if(pageNo == 1)
                page = mt.Find(_ => true).Limit(PAGE_SIZE).ToListAsync().Result;
            else
                page = mt.Find(_ => true).Skip(PAGE_SIZE * (pageNo -1)).Limit(PAGE_SIZE).ToListAsync().Result;
              if(page.Count() == 0)
              break;
            foreach (var p in page)
            {                    

                    ObjectId id = (ObjectId)p["_id"];
                    DeleteResult dr = mt.DeleteOneAsync(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id)).Result;
                    if (dr.IsAcknowledged)
                    {
                        if (dr.DeletedCount != 1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(string.Format("Count [value:{0}] after delete is invalid", dr.DeletedCount));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Delete for [_id:{0}] was not acknowledged", id.ToString()));


            }
            count += page.Count(); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done, count:{0}", count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the result from `DeleteOneAsync`? See http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_DeleteOneAsync.htm

Comment: @flindeberg Yes, did that there is no error coming up, and delete count is also ok. What I found more like a pattern is, it is able to process only half the count of total records and then it just don't process more.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the actual code that reproduces the problem instead? Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I could, but there is too much abstraction done over the original objects...I'll try to write some based on how the code executes..

Comment: @Mr767267 Thanks for the code. I'd say Sign's answer is correct then.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Well, I cannot say it's correct because I cannot write separate paging logic for reading and deleting. As the API cannot tell if the user is deleting or just updating within cursor, it would not be wise to ask the page 1 each time for delete and N page for update. I hope you understand the issue here. I need some way to tell the cursor to read from the updated recordset somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cursor is not isolated](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-isolation) so it recognizes that you've deleted some data and when you pull the next page you are skipping records you intend to delete. If you pulled page 1 each time it would work like what it seems you want it to.